# Android IAP v3 caching

Tags: android, in-app-purchase

[This](http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/api.html#caching) link states that Android IAP v3 has a local cache, so I can call `getPurhcases()` more often. I have a one-time non-consumable item (~premium version) in my app, so to me this tells that (opposed to many online examples) I do not have to save the flag whether the premium version has been bought... so can I just call `getPurchases()` any time I need this info (even on each fragment switch, ca 10-20 secs apart)? No performance penalty?
Does anyone have experience about using it like this?